# Can't see or run macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a bunch of macros in a workbook, which worked fine last time I opened it. Now, Monday morning, going to re-run some of them and I can neither see the macros when I go to Developer/Macros/This Workbook (or All Workbooks) nor when I open VBA editor. I can see the Modules but when I click on them, nothing comes up. Even opening an older version the same workbook has the same issue. Anyone seen this before? I didn't password protect it and neither has it been saved over by someone else. Closed & re-opened Excel & no dice. I reeeeeally don't want to have to re-write all these macros, so any help would be majorly appreciated.

[image: I can see the modules, but can't access them]

Comment: Is the Code window visible, but empty? Or is it closed/hidden - in which case does it return when you press `F7`?

Comment: " when I click on them, nothing comes up" - did you double-click on them? Clicking once doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can also try to right-click on a module and select `Export File...`. Save the file somewhere and open it with Notepad to see whether your code is actually there.

Comment: Yes, I double-clicked. Nothing opens when I double-click. I closed every other window with code & just the grey screen is still there. And I just tried exporting, it acts like it's exporting, but nothing is exported.

Comment: And F7 does nothing to bring anything up. :-(

Comment: It also won't let me insert a new module.

Comment: After double clicking to open one, use the Window pulldown at the top of the VBA window and select Cascade to see if that makes them appear.

Comment: Nope, window/cascade didn't work.